# kubectl : --dry-run is deprecated and can be replaced with --dry-run=client

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, kubeconfig

I have aws-eks cluster and below is my command to replace existing the configuration.

```
kubectl create configmap flink-config --from-file=./config -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl replace -
```

but when I run this command. it gives an error like

```
W1009 17:00:14.998329  323115 helpers.go:553] --dry-run is deprecated and can be replaced with --dry-run=client.
```

Will it do the same thing If I replace -dry-run to -dry-run=client?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

About `dry-run=client` we learn

> `--dry-run=client` flag to preview the object that would be sent to
> your cluster, without really submitting it.

And in the kubernetes API reference we read:

> Must be "none", "server", or "client". If client strategy, only print
> the object that would be sent, without sending it. If server strategy,
> submit server-side request without persisting the resource.

Performing local tests I realized that when I try to replace an existing config object using `dry-run=server`, the following error occurs. The apiserver told us that already exist a configmap with the name `flink-config`.

```
kubectl create configmap flink-config --from-file=./config -o yaml --dry-run=server
Error from server (AlreadyExists): configmaps "flink-config" already exists
```

However is I try with to use `dry-run=client` the object is not validated by the apiserver, that is, just by the client, so the yaml is printed to us:

```
kubectl create configmap flink-config --from-file=./config -o yaml --dry-run=client
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |
    FOO: foo
    MYVAR: hello
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: flink-config
```

So basically, yes, the `dry-run=client` it has the same effect than the deprecated `dry-run`. The equivalent flag for `dry-run=server` was `--server-dry-run` and became deprecated in v1.18.

Comment: @NIrav Modi if the answer was sufficient to answer your question, please mark it as a correct answer to helping others who may have the same doubt. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) you can read about the importance of accepting questions.